# docker web server does not shut even after deletion

Tags: tomcat, docker

I have an old docker image running a tomcat web server on port 8060, and recently, I deleted the old one(stop the container) and create a new docker image with a new tomcat web server running on the same port and IP address. 
Before I run the new image, I am sure the port 8060 is closed, but I could still get the old web server through browser, why?
And after I run the new image :

```
sudo docker run -t -p 8060:8060 adsfdss12231a
```

try http://MYIP:8060 through browser, it returns me the old server. 
I do not understand why, even the port is closed the web server can run?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: post `docker ps` and `docker ps -a`, and if on Linux `lsof -i:8060`

Comment: docker ps show my only one running container, docker ps -a shows all the containers I exited before. Does that mean those container I stopped before are still exist? I can run them again? How could I delete them? lsof -i:8060 returns nothing.  Thanks a lot